# How to limit the template parameter to only floating point type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Is there a way to limit a template parameter `T` to a specific type or category?

The below code works but I want to make it simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename T>
constexpr auto func( const T num ) -> T
{
    static_assert( std::is_floating_point_v<T>, "Floating point required." );

    return num * 123;
}

int main( )
{
    std::cout << func( 4345.9 ) << ' ' // should be ok
              << func( 3 ) << ' ' // should not compile
              << func( 55.0f ) << '\n'; // should be ok
}
```

I want to get rid of the `static_assert` and write something like this:

```
template < std::is_floating_point_v<T> >
constexpr auto func( const T num ) -> T
{
    return num * 123;
}
```

Any suggestions? Anything from *type_traits* or maybe *concepts* would be better.

Comment: @Aconcagua: then just overload for `float` and `double` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The below code works but I want to make it simpler:

You may combine [abbreviated function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) and the [`std::floating_point` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/floating_point) for a condensed constrained function template definition:

```
constexpr auto func(std::floating_point auto num) {
  return num * 123;
}
```

Note that this does not include an explicitly specified trailing return type `T` as in your original approach, but that for the current definition the deduced return type will be `decltype(num)`, which is either `float` or `double` (or impl-defined `long double`). As @Barry points out in the comments below, if you require a trailing return type, say for an overload with a ref- and cv-qualified function parameter, then the brevity gain of abbreviated templates is lost to the added cost of complex trailing return type.

```
// Contrived example: but if this was the design intent,
// then no: skip the abbreviated function template approach.
constexpr auto func(const std::floating_point auto& num) 
  -> std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(num)> { /* ... */ }

// ... and prefer
template<std::floating_point T>
constexpr auto func(const T& num) -> T  { /* ... */ }

// ... or (preferential)
template<std::floating_point T>
constexpr T func(const T& num) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Note that OP's code explicitly returned `-> T`, which you can't do with abbreviated function templates.

Comment: @Barry: Sure you can, with `decltype`.  (I seem to recall playing code golf on this subject before.)

Comment: @Barry I guess you could use `constexpr auto func(std::floating_point auto num) -> decltype(num)`, but it would not always be equivalent to `-> T` unless also taking into account e.g. removing cv-qualifiers.

Comment: Both your solution and the solution in the other answer seem to generate the same number of assembly codes though I did not examine line by line to make sure.  Do you think there can be any difference in some scenarios?

Comment: @digito_evo Our two solutions [are functionally equivalent](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#18.sentence-8) and there is no different whatsoever with regard to performance/generated assembly. Abbreviated function templates is just a syntactic sugar for regular function templates (with invented template parameters as compared to the explicitly declared type-template parameters in the template-head's of non-abbreviated function templates).

Comment: @Davis Once you need `decltype`, you might as well just not use abbreviated function templates. It both becomes longer and less readable.

Comment: @Barry: Right—but I didn’t say you should, and you did say that you can’t (which is true only syntactically).

Comment: @DavisHerring Fair

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`std::floating_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/floating_point) concept to constrain the type `T`:

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::floating_point T>
constexpr auto func( const T num ) -> T {
  return num * 123;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EMb4cbhK7)